# What happens to the older version of dlib when we install a new version into our system?

Tags: python, libraries, face-recognition, dlib

And also can we reinstall the old version of dlib again if newer one is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The old version is uninstalled and the new version is installed.

Do a `pip install dlib==<version_number>` to install the version you want.

Refer: [dlib version 18.17.100](https://pypi.org/project/dlib/18.17.100/)